# react js/ socket io server/slient side issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, socket.io, server-side

I am creating a chat app. Everything works fine on localhost, but when I upload files on hosting to use on website, I can't find the proper way to setting the file to work.

My steps after working local version was `npm run build` and `npm install -g serve` uploaded on hosting which after didn't work directly (index.html). After some changes I got it to work but the core of app won't work.

[every time i get error on client side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VHlo.png)

i tried different ports as direct ip/url on client side but still get some of errors...

The code which is use is this: Client side

```
import "./App.css";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { useState } from "react";
import Chat from "./Chat";

const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001");

function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
  const [showChat, setShowChat] = useState(false);

  const joinRoom = () => {
    if (username !== "" && room !== "") {
      socket.emit("join_room", room);
      setShowChat(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!showChat ? (
        <div className="joinChatContainer">
          <h3>Join A Chat</h3>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="John..."
            onChange={(event) => {
              setUsername(event.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Room ID..."
            onChange={(event) => {
              setRoom(event.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <button onClick={joinRoom}>Join A Room</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Chat socket={socket} username={username} room={room} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this one is server side

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);

  socket.on("join_room", (data) => {
    socket.join(data);
    console.log(`User with ID: ${socket.id} joined room: ${data}`);
  });

  socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
    socket.to(data.room).emit("receive_message", data);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User Disconnected", socket.id);
  });
});

server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("SERVER RUNNING");
});
```

Comment: Please include the error as formatted text rather than a link to an image. What browser? Does the same thing happen with extensions disabled?